# How to display all length without the last?

Tags: javascript, display

```
var id = "YuvalW";
var c = id.substr(id.length - 1);
alert(c);
```

I want to display only 'Yuval' with out 'W' ---
 how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var id = "YuvalW";
var c = id.substr(0, id.length - 1);
alert(c);
```